# Вставка swf с указанием родной директории

Tags: flash, html

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с проблемой. swf файл при вызове считает, что страница index является его родной директорий и пытается загрузить свои файлы из корня сайта (не лежащие там).

То есть, после вызова:
корень/settings.xml 
И соответственно ошибка.

Вызываю очень простым кодом найденным в интернете.

<object width="600" height="213"><param name="movie" value="корень/flashxml/imagescrollerfx/ImageScrollerFX.swf" />
</object>

Может кто-то подсказать, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый раз мне не ответили. SWF этот скомпилирован с шифром на некоторые файлы, и компиляторы не берут его (смог только удалить имэйдж-копирайт).

Вопрос решился в общем-то просто, с использованием iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Декомпилировать SWF, и изменить требуемые значения, или почитать доку по этому SWF файлу(если такая имеется) на предмет того, как указать ему путь...